# Check list from input added to string in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.5

Hi stack overflow community, I am working on a chess move predictor in Python 3 and have stumbled into an obstacle, the problem is that I'm trying to check a list of possible moves from a square depending on an input. However to show whether the move is for black or white I have to put say a w after it. How do I check the list which name is made of strings and inputs?
This is a list of possible moves for the first move:

```
    PWA2m = ["A3", "A4", "B3"]
    PWB2m = ["B3", "B4", "C3", "A3"]
    PWC2m = ["C3", "C4", "D3", "B3"]
    PWD2m = ["D3", "D4", "E3", "C3"]
    PWE2m = ["E3", "E4", "D3", "F3"]
    PWF2m = ["F3", "F4", "E3", "G3"]
    PWG2m = ["G3", "G4", "F3", "H3"]
    PWH2m = ["H3", "H4", "G3"]
    K1WB1m = ["A3", "C3"]
    K2WG1m = ["F3", "H3"]
```

And this is the checker so far:

```
     wmove = input("What square are you moving from?")
     if wmove == "":
       Piece = squares.get(wmove)
```

I would like it to output something like this if the user has put in a valid square:

```
    Possible Moves for PawnWhite:
    B3, B4, C3, A3
```

Comment: Is the problem that you need to check if B1 is one of your lists, e.g. if  wmove == "B1": return the list notated by PWB1m or something similar? If so, I'd recommend having a global dictionary or tree structure to store these

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: You don't have a list, you have several different variables that have lists assigned to them. What exactly are you trying to check? Can you give an example of your input/expected-output?

Comment: Please, give us an example of desired input/output as asked before.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I would like to check a certain variable with a list assigned to it but I can't check using the input for what square they're moving from and the string put together to one variable

Comment: Implementing the following might help in the future: [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to access the lists for different pieces by searching the names of the lists.  However, the names of variables shouldn't generally be accessed by the program.  A simple solution to your problem is to use a `dict` to store the pieces and their lists of possibilities:

```
current_state = {"A1":"Kw", "B5":"Qb"} # and so on
current_possibilities = {"A1": ["B2", "A2"], "B5":["B4", "B6", "C4", "C5", "C6"]}
```

Then, you can access the current piece locations/where they can move quite simply:

```
print("The piece at {} is a {} and can move to: {}".format(
    input, current_state[input][:-1], current_possibilities[input]))
```

Which, given the input `"A1"` above, will then print:

```
The piece at A1 is a K and can move to: ['B4', 'B6', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6']
```

Comment: Thank You, Ben G a great answer I couldn't have thought of myself. 2 up for the best man